# Select Top 1 records from MS SQL using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am using the below `@Query` annotation to get the first few record from MS-SQL. It's showing error saying "< operator > or AS expected..."

```
   @Query("SELECT Top 1 * FROM NEVS010_VEH_ACTV_COMMAND C WHERE C.EVS014_VIN = :vin ORDER BY C.EVS010_CREATE_S DESC")
    CommandStatus findCommandStatusByVinOrderByCreatedTimestampDesc(@Param("vin") String vin);
```

Comment: Please make sure to include the actual exception including stack trace in your questions, formatted as code. Makes identifying what is going wrong much easier.

Comment: I use Spring 2.0.8 and I must to change Top to first and it works like a charm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the query is SQL (and not JPQL) one needs to set `nativeQuery = true` in the annotation:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT Top 1 * FROM NEVS010_VEH_ACTV_COMMAND C WHERE C.EVS014_VIN = :vin ORDER BY C.EVS010_CREATE_S DESC")
    CommandStatus findCommandStatusByVinOrderByCreatedTimestampDesc(@Param("vin") String vin);
```

Answer (score 22):

You can also use findFirst and findTop as mentioned in the [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result):

```
findFirstByVinOrderByCreatedTimestampDesc(String vin)
```

Answer (score 0):

For custom Queries without using nativeQuery, the field `ROWNUM` can be used.

Ex (in Kotlin but the same idea works in Java):

```
@Query("""
    SELECT a 
    FROM Account a 
    WHERE a.bla = :ble
        AND ROWNUM = 1 
    ORDER BY a.modifiedDate DESC 
""")
fun findWhatever(@Param("ble") someParam: String)
```

> I haven't found that on any doc so far. I just tested and it worked for Oracle, MySQL and H2